# Accumulation points of $\{x \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \|x\| = 1\}$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following set:

$$B=\{x \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \|x\| = 1\}$$

and I would like to find all it's accumulation points. I have already found the interior, which seems to be empty, but I am having some trouble proving that $B$ itself is the set of all accumulation points.

Edit: So I followed one of the hints I was given to write up my own proof:

Let $x\in B$. Suppose there exists an $m\in B$. Then $$||m-x|| \le ||m||-||x|| = 0$$

so $$||m-x|| < \epsilon\ \ \ \  \forall\epsilon >0$$
This implies that $m$ must automatically be in the epsilon circle around $B$, so the intersection of $B$ and the epsilon circle around $x$ is not empty.

Comment: Fix a point $x \in B$. You have to show that for any neighbourhood $A$ of $x$, there exists $y \in A$ such that $y \ne x$ and $y \in B$.
Remember how the induced  topology on $B$ is defined..

Comment: If proving it directly fails, try contradiction. What happens if some point in B is not an accumulation point?

Comment: @G.Snapsmath I tried to proof it a bit differently now, but I think I just showed that any point in $B$ must be an accumulation point as well, which is trivial I guess. I tried to find a contradiction, but I would end up with $||m|| < \epsilon+1  $ which would not imply that $||m|| \neq 1$.

Comment: You have the triangle inequality backwards.  $\|m-x\|+\|x\|\geq \|(m-x)+x\|=\|m\| .$  So $\|m-x\|\geq \|m\|-\|x\|.$  Also if $\|m-x\|=0$ then $m=x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the Euclidean norm $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}.$

1. For $j\in \{1,2\}$ let $P_j=(\cos a_j,\sin a_j)\in B.$ Then $$\|P_1-P_2\|=\sqrt {2-2\cos (a_1-a_2)}=2|\sin ((a_1-a_2)/2)|.$$ So for  $r>0,$  any $P_2$ such that $0<|a_2-a_1|<\min (2\pi,r)$ satisfies $$0<\|P_1-P_2\|=2|\sin ((a_1-a_2)/2)|\leq 2 |(a_1-a_2)/2|=|a_1-a_2|<r.$$
2. If $P\in \mathbb R^2$ and $\|P\|\ne 1$  let $r=\|P\|.$

   (i). If $r>1$ then any $P'$ such that $\|P-P'\|<(r-1)/2$ satisfies $$\|P'\|\geq \|P\|-\|P-P'\|\geq  r-(r-1)/2=(r+1)/2>1$$  so $P'\not \in B.$

   (ii). If $r<1$ then any $P'$ such that $\|P-P'\|<(1-r)/2$ satisfies $$\|P'\|\leq \|P'-P\|+\|P\|<(1-r)/2 +r=(1+r)/2<1$$ so $P'\not \in B.$

Answer (score 2):

we claim that there is no accumulation point outside the set $B$. If possible let there exist a point $x$ does not belong to $B$ is an accumulation point of $B$ then the line from the origin to $x$ intersect a point in $B$,say $y$,take $r$ <$d$$(x$,$y)$ .Then the open ball $D(x;r)$ does not intersect $B$. Hence $x$ is not the accumulation point.